# kafka-node - pass arguments to async function consumer.on();

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using [kafka-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node) for my node.js server - for connecting to kafka topics. In their API there is a callback function:

```
consumer.on('message', function (message) {
     console.log(message);
});
```

for consuming messages when they arrived.

I wonder if and how can I add an argument to this callback function since I'm not the one who call it when message arrive.

To be more specific, I want to send the expected ID and compare it with the consumed message id:

```
consumer.on('message', function (message, id) {
    if (id == message.id) 
        console.log(message);
});
```

**EDIT:**
This is a snippet of a larger code. 
The full flow is:

1. User ask http request from the node.js server.
2. GET HTTP request is tiggered in node.js server.
3. kafka producer send some message (with unique id) to external system and wait for a respond.
4. respond is received to kafka consumer. The received message id is compared to the expected id - if equal - return the message as http respond.

Consider that multiple http get request can received in parallel.

Comment: Lets assume, the event pass the second parameter called id, but then `id == message.id`  is going to be always `true`. So what exactly you expect here ?

Comment: @Oxi I've edit the post to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add arguments to the callback. But I believe you can achieve what you are trying to do without that -- just by referring to a variable that is within scope of the closure.

For example, if you have:

```
var id = 1001;

consumer.on('message', function(message) {
  if (id == message.id) console.log(message);
});
```

I believe this will do what you want.

Comment: I wonder if there is a different approach.. but I guess not. I'll try it and update..